# The type org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java

Actually i  added axis2-adb-1.1.jar file into build path and i have import statement "import org.apache.axis2.rpc.client.RPCServiceClient;".

Then i created an instance for it and i used that instance in the following statement.

```
Object[] response = serviceClient.invokeBlocking(
                        name, inputParams, returnTypes);
```

Here, serviceClient is an instance of "RPCServiceClient".

But i am getting error The type org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

Anyone could help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 3):

You also need an axiom-api JAR file.  Refer to this page - http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement - for the possibilities.  (You may need to refer to the axis2 documentation or download page to figure out which version you need.)

Comment: site seems to be having some issues.  I used: http://www.findjar.com/index.x?query=axiom-api